# PostgreSQL query performance and variations

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an *event* table with the following columns `user_id`, `points`, `created`. What I need to is to get all points for given month, total points and total rank for given `user_id`. I need to do it in a single query which resulted in the following attempt:

```
select
    e.user_id,
    sum(e.points) as total_points,
    (select sum(points) from event where user_id = 1 and extract(month from created) = 1) as month_points,
    (select rank from (select user_id as id, rank() over (order by sum(points) desc) from event group by user_id) as rank where id = 1)
from
    event pte
where
    e.user_id = 1
group by
    e.user_id
;
```

What I'd like to ask is:

1. Can this query be slow?
2. Can it be done better / in an another way?
3. Is `rank` function reliable enough or it has been misused?

Comment: 1) it will be very fast, because it contains an error (in the second subselect) . 2) Yes: correct the error 3) depends on the intention of the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming postgresql version greater or equal to 9.4, you can use aggregate `filter` clause to avoid subselects for `month_points` and `rank`:

```
select * from
    (select
        e.user_id,
        sum(e.points) as total_points,
        sum(points) filter (where extract(month from created) = 1) as month_points,
        rank() over (order by sum(points) desc)
    from
        event e
    group by
        e.user_id
    ) as inner_query
where user_id = 1;
```

Comment: Does it make this query to perform better? What if I can't use 9.4?

Comment: `filter` isn't implemented in earlier pg versions. Performance? It depends: if table `event` is small or there is no index on `user_id` my query should perform better (but it's better to check it on your own).

Comment: Thanks. There's and index, it's a foreign key.

Comment: @Opal: the `filter()` expression can be replaced with a corresponding `sum(case when ... end)` expression